# Manipulate/creation of SVGs relative to their center

Tags: svg

I would like to identify the center of an SVG, so that I can manipulate multiple SVGs with ease.

I am trying to make multiple examples of the basic polygons (3 to 8 sides), and quickly realized that I either hade to make my own, which involves a lot of math, or I could pull from  wikipedia the current ones.   The problem with the former is that it takes a lot of time to translate the coordinates from Sketchup.  The problem with the latter is that they are oriented differently and of different size.

I know that you can transform, scale, and rotate the SVG, but I need to know the coordinates of the center of the SVG.   How do I find this out, so I can set universal manipulations?

Take the `transform="rotate(degrees x y)"`, I need to know the center to accomplish this.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/2BBjy/)
Here, I would like to set all the centers to the same, and then scale them to the same height and width, and potentially rotate them individually so that they all have a flat bottom, not a vertex.

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer to your question isn't obvious...

It might be simpler for polygons, particularly convex polygons: you can iterate on the path and find its bounding box by computing the max and min of the x and y coordinates of each point of the path.

Then you can decide that the center of the shape is the center of the of the bounding box.

An alternative is to put an invisible element at what you estimate to be the center (for complex shapes, the concept of "center" can be variable), and get its coordinates to find out where the center is. Particularly for rotating purpose: you might want to do this rotation around a specific point which might not be the geometrical center.

Comment: You don't have to iterate over a path or polygon to find out the bounding box, there's the getBBox() method.

Comment: @ThomasW The original question doesn't state explicitly any language or context, except by the JSFiddle link... So this function isn't necessarily available. I admit I was reasoning in terms of Processing, where such function doesn't exist. But you are right to mention it for cases where it is available.